# Strange symbols appearing in Excel CSV export after bullet points

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, excel-2010

I have written a method to export data in a CSV format to Excel.  Most people's Excel document look fine, however some Excel documents have a question mark in a box symbol after the bullet points in one of the columns.  The data is exactly the same people are looking at.  Is this something I can fix in the code, or is there a setting that needs to be changed in Excel to not display these strange symbols after bullet points?

Comment: Could you add a snippet of the offending CSV to the question?  It's really hard to answer it otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

This usually means there is a symbol that the default font on the user's system is unable to interpret. Since CSV is raw text, your 2 choices are:

1. Find the symbol causing it and replace it with a more friendly (universal) symbol
2. Encourage users to use a specific font that has a larger character set (Arial/Verdana/etc).

Comment: The export has been tested on Excel 2010 and Excel2003, 1 person has encountered these symbols so far, while the others haven't.  So you think I should check what the default font is set to on this person's computer who is receiving these strange symbols?

Comment: I tried removing the symbol like this but it had no effect:  .Replace("^010", "");

Comment: @ScrumGuy000: Well it won't be the symbol being displayed on the bad system. You need to figure out which symbol in your file that it correlates to and then perform the replace on THAT symbol. `^010` will only be a text display of what that system THINKS the symbol really is. You need to replace the actual symbol.

Comment: Thanks for your help...I think I've fixed it, I had to remove \t, I will know for sure when the person with the problem tests the export.